# wordpress & iframe: how to correctly append a php snippets return value to a 'src=' link (in an iframe)

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, hyperlink, append

I am trying to embed a Google maps iframe (in a wordpress 'custom html' block).
the original (working) code snippet with the location hardcoded looks like this:

```html
 <iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  style="border:0"
  loading="lazy"
  allowfullscreen
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?
key=aaaappppiiiikkkeeeyyyy&q=Abbey Road, London, NW10 7TR">
</iframe>
```

now i have a php code snippet that dynamically returns the location of a user profile, e.g. "Abbey Road, London, NW10 7TR"

what i try to achieve is using the shortcode that returns the php snippets return value (location) in the 'src=' address, basically kinda like this (non working) example:

```html
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=aaaappppiiiikkkeeeyyyy&q="
[wpcode id="123"]>
```

i searched and attempted many suggested solutions, but no success yet.
what is correct way to attach my shortcode/location in the iframes 'src='  ?

edit: php snippet added:

```css
um_fetch_user( $user_id );
    $street_work   = um_user( 'street_work' );
    $city_work  = um_user( 'city_work' );
    $country_work  = um_user( 'country_work' );
$location= $street_work . "," . $city_work . "," . $country_work;
echo $location;
```

edit4:
Following the advice given here i now have this code in my php code snippet (semicolon in iframe line added):

```css
um_fetch_user( $user_id );
    $street_work   = um_user( 'street_work' );
    $city_work  = um_user( 'city_work' );
    $country_work  = um_user( 'country_work' );
$location= $street_work . "," . $city_work . "," . $country_work;

$iframe= '<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  style="border:0"
  loading="lazy"
  allowfullscreen
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=aaaapppiiiikkkeeeyy
    &q="' . $location . '></iframe>';

return $iframe;
```

sadly this also does not work (tried putting the shortcode into a shortcode block and also into a custom html block, but both dont give me the desired result

Comment: Please add the php code that you have tried and if you're adding your Iframe code in custom HTML then I don't think shortcode will work there. You need to create a shortcode that returns an iframe code and in the shortcode param you need to pass the id or location that you want with the iframe src.

Comment: added the php snippet, and this works, as i can see the return value is indeed the users given address (when i add the shortcode to the page outside the iframe it displays the correct address, comma separated).  I indeed add the iframe in a 'custom html' block.

Comment: Then it will be good to return the complete `iframe` code from the shortcode with the dynamic location.

Comment: thnx Vijay, i tried to follow your advice, but i assume i made some mistake there... updated original post with new snippet

Comment: Please add the complete shortcode code with shortcode attributes, function name, shortcode name, and how you're called the shortcode. *Note: a shortcode should not echo anything, it should only return the final output, wordpress will echo the output.*

Comment: i dont have that - i use the 'wp code' plugin (that holds my snippet as posted in my original post edit2), and the 'wp code' plugin gives me the option to either 'auto insert' the snippet or use it as shortcode: [wpcode id="123"]

Comment: and i have chosen use snippet as shortcode and have pasted the shortcude [wpcode id="281"] into the WP shortcode block

Comment: Ok, then change `echo $iframe;` line to `return $iframe;` you can only `return` from the shortcode.

Comment: thnx again, tried the last advice, but even with 'return $iframe' it does not work (no iframe shows on mypage at all)

Comment: You can try to `return 'hello world';` and remove `return $iframe;` to make test if your shortcode actually works or not. if `hello world` shows on the page then your shortcode plugin might not allowing the `iframe` tag.

Comment: OMG - something is very weird, I removed all code but `return 'hello'` ;  and not even 'hello' shows on my page - which is totally weird, as i could succesfully display the adress earlier (using `echo 'location';`)

Comment: You might be having typos or other minor mistakes that you can't identify. I can't tell what exactly you're doing wrong without knowing what you changed. However In the code that is available on the question. you're mission semicolon `(;)` on the iframe code line. so if you'll this kind of mistake, 100% chances are code will not run, since it will return the error and your shortcode plugin will catch the error and won't execute anything.

Comment: i now tried `return 'hello';` -> no hello shows on page.   i then switched to `echo 'hello;'` and now hello indeed shows...   i have no clue why `return` does nothing, but `echo` does (all other code is removed from the snippet for now).   seems to be that return for some weird reason does not return the string

Comment: edit 4: added semicolon, snipped again as showing in original post -> still no joy

Comment: i now changed `return` to `echo` - now an iframe shows!   but it shows error 'invalid q parameter'

Answer (score 1):

After fixing your code and typos, this is how the code should be.
If iframe markup is blocked by your shortcode plugin then you will have to create a custom shortcode and add to your theme `functions.php` file.

```
// Prepare api args.
$api_args = array( 'key' => 'aaaapppiiiikkkeeeyy' );

// Set default location for non loggedin users.
$location = '';

// Get user id. if you're getting user id from other ways then change the next line.
$user_id = um_profile_id();

// Check if the user id is available.
if ( $user_id ) {

    // Fetch user.
    um_fetch_user( $user_id );
    $street_work  = um_user( 'street_work' );
    $city_work    = um_user( 'city_work' );
    $country_work = um_user( 'country_work' );

    // Filter empty values and join with a comma (,).
    $location = join( ', ', array_filter( array( $street_work, $city_work, $country_work ) ) );

    // If the location is not empty then add in API args with param "q".
    if ( ! empty( $location ) ) {
        $api_args['q'] = esc_attr( $location );
    }
}

// Build API url with API args.
$api_url = add_query_arg( $api_args, 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place' );
$iframe  = '<iframe width="600" height="450" style="border:0" loading="lazy" allowfullscreen referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade" src="' . esc_url( $api_url ) . '"></iframe>';

return $iframe;
```

#### UPDATE

**Since I don't have the Ultimate member plugin installed I have tried the above code without `um` functions, with the below code:**

Short tag used `[demo_shortcode]`

My shortcode displayed the `iframe` code properly and it returns the API error as expected [screenshot](https://snipboard.io/aMnNZI.jpg)

```
add_shortcode(
    'demo_shortcode',
    function() {
        // Prepare api args.
        $api_args = array( 'key' => 'aaaapppiiiikkkeeeyy' );

        $location = 'Abbey Road, London, NW10 7TR';

        if ( ! empty( $location ) ) {
            $api_args['q'] = esc_attr( $location );
        }
        // Build API url with API args.
        $api_url = add_query_arg( $api_args, 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place' );
        $iframe  = '<iframe width="600" height="450" style="border:0" loading="lazy" allowfullscreen referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade" src="' . esc_url( $api_url ) . '"></iframe>';

        return $iframe;
    }
);
```